# Time format/ data display changes following join then export to data

Tags: arcmap, data, attribute-joins, table, time

I am working on a simple join of data in an excel table to create an attribute table from kml's that were converted to polygons. The join works perfectly, however when exporting the data as a new shapefile (necessary to make join permanent) some of the data in the table does not display or changes format. For instance, time data is changed to all noon instead of individual times and some of the table field headings disappear even though they were present in the join. \

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to GIS SE. Please include which software you are using, and sample data/screenshots to illustrate your issue

Comment: I have just added images of the table joined to polygons before exporting as a shaprefile and a photo of it afterwards. You can see the times all change to 12:00:00 AM. I am using ArcMap 10.8.1

Comment: what are you exporting too? Shapefiles don't support date/time fields...

Comment: Exporting to Shapefile. Shapefiles do support date and time. They are a data type. And you can see in the image above the date field data has fidelity when it's exported to Shapefile. Thank you.